# How to handle expiration of JWT Token in Spring Boot for Login/Logout feature? Java and Flutter

Tags: java, flutter, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am working on a **Spring Boot Project** where I need to implement following functionality:

1. I need to secure the REST APIs using JWT Authentication (using Spring Security). (I am familiar with this part.)
2. I need to give the token to the user **(a flutter mobile app)**, when the user logs in on the phone.
3. The user sends the token with each API call which is validated on the Spring Boot server and when validated, data is sent to the user. The token should be valid unless the user is logged out on his mobile app.
4. When the user logs out from the app on his device, the token should be invalidated so that it cannot be used again.

**Problems I am facing:**
a. We set an **expiration time for the token on the server side**. Now if the expiration time is 1 hour, and user (who is logged in on the app) tries to make an API call after that, it will be **unauthorized.** **User should be able to make API calls unless logged out.** (This is the general behavior we see on mobile apps.)
b. When the user **logs out, the JWT token should be expired** and it should not permit any more requests.

So, I need help to implement this complete **login/logout functionality when using JWT token to secure APIs.** Please tell if its possible to do it with JWT itself or I need to do something else.

Comment: It is possible. You mentioned you set the expiration, does it mean you already have the server working? If so, you should already have the endpoints available to do everything you need (login, logout and refresh)

Comment: Yes, as I said I have protected my APIs with JWT Bearer token. I have set an expiration time for the token. But I need the functionality as mentioned in point 3 and 4. I have actually protected my APIs but not implemented login/logout feature like we usually find in mobile apps.